# Passport-ldapauth : Missing Credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, ldap, passport.js

I'm trying to create LDAP authentication with [Passport's Ldap library](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth) and I'm getting the following error:

> {
>       "message": "Missing credentials" }

Here is the code:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LdapStrategy = require("passport-ldapauth");

let OPTS = {
  server: {
    url: "ldap://<xxxx>:389",
    bindDN: "dc=xxx-it,dc=com",
    searchBase: "ou=people",
    searchFilter: "(uid={{username}})"
  },
  usernameField: "username"
};

passport.use(
  new LdapStrategy(OPTS, (user, done) => {
    return done(null, user);
  })
);
```

---

```
  app.post("/api/test", (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate("ldapauth", { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
      var error = err || info;
      if (error) return res.status(401).json(error);
      if (!user)
        return res.json(404, {
          message: "Something went wrong, please try again."
        });
      var token = auth.signToken(user._id, user.role);
      res.json({ token: token });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

How should I send the username? Should I specify the bindCredentials field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was console.log the values. For some reason which I don't know, the terminal doesn't read this Json object.

I tested in Postman and the values are ok.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: Hi Luis,

I have same problem. { "message": "Missing credentials" }

Can you please post the updated code.

Comment: I don't have access to it anymore. Can you make sure you actually didn't put your credentials wrong?